# prepareForSegue:sender : Not load data

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have problem with this method `prepareForSegue:sender` it not load data from my Plist when I tap cell. And it doesn't have error.

View.m

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    NSString *identifier = segue.identifier;

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"DataDetail"]) {
        //First get the data
        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
        NSMutableDictionary *data = self.datas[selectedIndexPath.row];

        DataDetailViewController *dataDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        dataDetailViewController.data = data;
    }   
}



-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self) {
        NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"plist"];
        NSArray *nonMutableBirthdays = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

        self.datas = [NSMutableArray array];

        NSMutableDictionary *dataDic;
        NSDictionary *dictionary;
        NSString *name;
        NSString *pic;
        UIImage *image;
        NSString *detail;

        for (int i=0;i<[nonMutableBirthdays count];i++) {
            dictionary = [nonMutableBirthdays objectAtIndex:i];
            name = dictionary[@"name"];
            pic = dictionary[@"pic"];
            image = [UIImage imageNamed:pic];
            detail= dictionary[@"detail"];
            dataDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            dataDic[@"name"] = name;
            dataDic[@"image"] = image;
           dataDic[@"detail"] = detail;

            [self.datas addObject:dataDic];
        }
    }

    return self;
}
```

and DataDetailViewController.m

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"viewWillAppear");
    NSString *name = self.data[@"name"];
    self.title = name;
    UIImage *image = self.data[@"image"];
    self.photoView.image = image;
    NSString *detail = self.data[@"detail"];
    self.TextView.text= detail;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: is `initWithCoder:` called?

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in your `prepareForSegue` to see if it is called?  If so, what happens when you single step through it.  As @Larme said, what about `initWithCoder`?  I would suggest `viewDidLoad` is a better place for initialisation

Comment: @Larme, As Paulw11 said, check prepareForSegue is getting called? If not sure just log the "data" after the line NSMutableDictionary *data = self.datas[selectedIndexPath.row];
And check whether you are calling deselectRowAtIndexPath: of UITableView in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: